# How to use Closure to recycle code in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I would like to use Closures (or possibly some other technique) to eliminate repetitive code in Swift.

Here is (a simplified version of) what I have:

**hasAboveThreshold**

```
func hasAboveThreshold(data: [Double], threshold: Double) -> Bool {
    for i in 0..<data.count {
        if data[i] > threshold {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**hasBetweenThreshold**

```
func hasBetweenThreshold(data: [Double], threshold1: Double, threshold2: Double) -> Bool {
    for i in 0..<data.count {
        if threshold2 > data[i] && data[i] > threshold1 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

In actual code, these functions are each about 25 lines long.

The ONLY difference in these two functions is the condition in the `if` statement.

I feel like having two essentially identical functions is redundant, and would like to combine them into one single function, that takes in a Closure (aka lambda) as part of its parameter(s)?

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the already existing answers, functions allow you a high degree of reusability, and for your particular example, high-order functions might work.

Let's begin with defining the basic blocks for the data comparison operations you want to do:

```swift
/// Creates a function that acts as a comparator against the received value
func isGreater<T: Comparable>(than value: T) -> (T) -> Bool {
    return { $0 > value }
}

/// Creates a function that checks if the argument in betwen the two bounds
func isWithin<T: Comparable>(_ lower: T, and upper: T) -> (T) -> Bool {
    return { lower..<upper ~= $0 }
}

/// Creates a function that checks if an array contains elements that satisfy the given predicate
func contains<T>(_ predicate: @escaping (T) -> Bool) -> ([T]) -> Bool {
    return { $0.contains(where: predicate) }
}
```

Both of the above functions create as and return a new function that can be stored and reused anywhere in your app.

Now, let's put the functions to good use:

```swift
func hasAboveThreshold(threshold: Double) -> ([Double]) -> Bool {
    return contains(isGreater(than: threshold))
}

func hasBetweenThreshold(threshold1: Double, threshold2: Double) -> ([Double]) -> Bool {
    return contains(isWithin(threshold1, and: threshold2))
}
```

Note how every piece (function) from the first code snippet was reused via function composition. Thus, you achieve the reusability goal.

Usage example:

```swift
let numbers = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]
let hasBetween1AndTen = hasBetweenThreshold(threshold1: 1.0, threshold2: 10.0)
print(hasBetween1AndTen(numbers))
```

As you store the `hasBetween1AndTen` into a variable, you can reuse it an any time, and in any place that has access to that variable.

Comment: THIS is actually what I what looking for! The only problem is I find this not so easy to follow (maybe that's just me), and frankly I'm not confident if I could explain everything step-by-step with this approach if someone asked me to do so. I will stick with rmaddy's answer for this project, but I will keep this solution in mind for future projects should a similar situation arise.

Comment: @kc_dev, yeah, Functional Programming has a stepper learning curve than Imperative Programming. Still, wherever possible, I opt in for FP since it usually generates more robust and modular code.

Comment: So instead of just writing `let hasBetween1AndTen = numbers.contains { $0 > 1.0 && $0 < 10.0 }`, you have to write two additional functions (which add overhead when performance is critical), then call the first which gives back a closure, then call the closure which will call `contains` which will then use the second function over and over.

Comment: @rmaddy the answer contains all the needed pieces. `hasBetweenThreshold` returns a function that operates on an array of Doubles, and that function is called with the `numbers` array. Regarding performance, I don't want to get into debates on this topic, we all know that "premature optimization is the root of all evil" :).

Comment: @Cristik I didn't say anything about your answer missing any pieces. I was simply comparing the need to write one simple line of code versus writing two lines of code plus two (reusable) functions. While your answer demonstrates some fancy functional programming, in the end it seems to add a lot of unnecessary overhead and complexity. My note was more for the OP so they can better understand. And I mentioned performance due to the comment the OP left below my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree, this solution is more verbose, however on the other hand every tiny function from the answer can be reused to build bigger functionalities, and in the context of a larger project this can help. And yes, if performance is an important aspect, then the OP might want to directly use the primitive functionality. But again, on the other hand, depending on how his code is structured the performance impact of the high order functions might be unnoticeable (e.g. if the built closures are cached instead of being re-created every time)

Answer (score 1):

Swift already provides what you want. Use the `contains(where:)` method of Array.

```
let numbers = [3.14, 5.7, 1.2, 6.7]

// Your hasAboveThreshold
let threshold = 4.0
let hasAbove = numbers.contains { $0 > threshold }

// Your hasBetweenThreshold
let lower = 2.0
let upper = 6.0
let hasBetween = numbers.contains { $0 > lower && $0 < upper }

print(hasAbove, hasBetween)
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Do you know the performance of your solution? I did not mention it in my original post, but this is a time-critical task.

Is 'contains' significantly faster than spelling out the function? (or vice-versa?)

Or is there no significant difference in performance?

Obviously, the fewer lines the better, but a few extra lines of code is worth it if there's a significant improvement in performance.

Comment: The performance of `contains` should be the same as your original code. It should return as soon as the closure returns true. But the only way to be certain is to do real performance tests. Build proper unit tests that measure performance. Do not attempt to compare in a playground.